# dispose() and detachChild

Tags: java, android, andengine

First, I apologize for my poor english.
i am creating a game where i have to throw balls. After a timer i want the ball disapear. So i try to detach it and dispose it. The ball become invisible but is still in my scene because the player is blocked when he's walking on it.
Have you an idea about why the ball is not completly destroy?

private void fire() {

```
    ballon = new Sprite(this.player.getX() + 15, this.player.getY() -5, resourcesManager.ballon_region,vbom);
    ballon.setScale(2f);
    BallonBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.physicsWorld, ballon, BodyType.DynamicBody, mFixtureDef);
   this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ballon, BallonBody, true, true));
   final Vector2 speed = Vector2Pool.obtain(20, 0);
   BallonBody.setLinearVelocity(speed);
   Vector2Pool.recycle(speed);
   attachChild(ballon);

       engine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1.6f, new ITimerCallback()
        {                                    
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
            {
                //ballon.dispose();
                ballon.detachSelf();
                ballon=null;

            }
        }));
}
```

Edit : **Ok , I've  found the problem. I just have to destroy the body too.**

Comment: don't edit your question with the answer, write an answer yourself and pick it as a correct answer